# resizing thumbnail from MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, resize, mpmovieplayercontroller

im trying to resize a thumbnail from a video captured using a UIImagePickerController using MPMoviePlayerController. here is what im using:

```
         self.moviePlayer.contentURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        UIImage *thumbnail = [self.moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:1 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
        self.thumbnailImage = [self resizeImage:thumbnail toWidth:75.0 andHeight:75.0];
```

and here is my resize method:

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image toWidth:(float)width andHeight:(float)height {

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [self.image drawInRect:newRect];
    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resizedImage;

}
```

the resize method works for photos captured in the imagePicker, but for some reason the image is blank when I use it on the video thumbnail. if I dont resize it it appears fine but for some reason resizing it messes it up. im using ios7 and testing on an iPhone 5s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:newRect];
UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I was using [self.image drawInRect] instead of [image drawInRect] stupid mistake. wow.